# Extend default authorization policy - is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

Currently I'm using .NET 7 with Minimal API.

I've created several methods in WebApplicationBuilder extension class, for Default policy set:

```
private static void AddDefaultAuthorization(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = builder.GetBasicAuthorizationPolicy();
        });
    }

    private static AuthorizationPolicy GetBasicAuthorizationPolicy(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var settings = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<AppSettings>();

        return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddRequirements(
                new ContinentRequirement(settings.Continent)
                )
            .Build();
    }
```

As you can see, my default authorization - require authenticated user and ContinentRequirement.

I'm also using Minimal API, with RouteGroupBuilder:

```
internal static class Upload
{
    public static RouteGroupBuilder MapUploadImages(this RouteGroupBuilder routes)
    {
        routes.MapPost("/upload/images", () => Results.Ok())
            .WithName("UploadImages")
            .WithPermissions(Permission.Upload);

        return routes;
    }
}
```

What do I want to do - add to this route a new authorization requirement, based on permissions. But - previous, default requirements (authenticated user, continent requirement) should work too.

I can do like this:

```
 public static RouteHandlerBuilder WithPermissions(this RouteHandlerBuilder builder, string[] permissions)
    {
        return builder
            .RequireAuthorization(gp => gp.AddRequirements(
            new PermissionRequirement(permissions));
    }
```

but this will add ONLY permission requirement to this route - default authorization requirement will not be called.

Ant ideas? Is it possible to set several requirements as DEFAULT, and just extend them for different routes?

Comment: Hi, did you mean you want to add all the permission to the WithPermissions extension method? It seems your parameter accept a string[] type, it cannot work by passing all the permission you want?

Comment: @Rena Hello, thanks! I updated my answer. Basically, I need to find how can I have default requirements and have the possibility to add new requirements with them at the same time